# Can human hair, animal fur and birds feather get cancer?

Tags: cancer, skin, hair

Hair, fur and feather protect skin from cancer(sun UV light).
I am interested can human hair, mammal fur or birds feather get cancer?

(Some migration birds like swifts spent 10 months in year in the air, without landing, but I never heard that birds get feather cancer.)

Comment: Hair and feathers are not living tissue, they are just proteins, mostly forms of keratin. Some skin cancers may start in hair follicles.